# Visual Studio 2019 test explorer switched to "OR" filtering since 16.2.x

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2019, xunit.net

I upgrade Visual Studio 2019 pretty quickly when changes come out, most recently to version 16.2.3. Right now my Test Explorer filters *differently* from before. I used to be able to add multiple filters and they would be *combined* with "AND" filtering (like any sane search box), but since the new version it does "OR" filtering:

[image: see description below]

The image shows tests filtered for the search string `Bar People` and these are my tests:

```
public class BarTests
{
    [Fact] public void People_can_do_stuff() { }
    [Fact] public void Elephants_can_do_stuff() { }
}

public class GaaTests
{
    [Fact] public void People_can_do_stuff() { }
    [Fact] public void Elephants_can_do_stuff() { }
}
```

However, as you can see, it shows all tests with *either* "Bar" *or* "People. I want only tests that fall under *both* terms. If I recall correctly, before the update VS2019 used to do this.

I'm not sure if it's important, but I'm using xUnit as my testing framework here.

It seems [version 16.2.1 has release notes mentioning big changes to the Test Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#test-explorer) so I'm guessing that's about when things started to work differently?

How can I make the Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer treat my filters as "AND" queries?

Comment: I am using VS2019 professional and I am also facing issue in Test explorer https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPhD.png

Comment: For me it's already OR in 16.2.2. I haven't tried older versions.

Comment: Thx @gdir for confirming that. It _was_ one of the recent updates that changed this, it seems [16.2.1 has a mention of this in its release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#test-explorer)

Comment: Reported the problem https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/726070/vs-2019-test-explorer-unable-to-and-multiple-filte.html

Please upvote the linked problem report if you have the same problem!